# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, when summing up a list - Python

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm having trouble using sum for summing up list items. It always gives me the following error: TypeError: "'int' object is not callable". The questions was asked before, and the best response was the code below:

```
a = range(10)
# [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = sum(a)
print(b)
# prints 45
```

It also gives me the same error. Can anyone help me out? I'm using Spyder (python 3.5)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You set `sum` to an integer: `sum = 42`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bound the name `sum` to an integer:

```
>>> sum = 42
>>> sum(range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Python doesn't prevent you from using the same name for a built-in function; it is your responsibility to not use those names if you need to use the built-in. Rename the `sum` variable in your code, or if this is in the interpreter, simply delete the variable:

```
>>> sum
42
>>> del sum
>>> sum(range(10))
45
```

Comment: Thanks! But how then do I sum up a list/array?

Comment: @MarkdeJonge: did you look at the last example? The built-in `sum()` function works just fine for that, my code example summed the sequence produced by `range(10)` there.

Comment: Ah thanks! My console still had the variable loaded..